# Upgrading to Spring 5 - 404 page not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am in the middle of upgrading a legacy project. Currently upgrading from spring 4 to spring 5.

The login works fine but the user is taken to the change password screen due to an out of date password. However, i am met with a 404 error not found when trying to reach it.

I think i have updated it correctly to meet the requirements for spring 5 but it still doesnt seem to map correctly. Can anyone spot something wrong inside my controller?

the path of the jsp for reference is

/application/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/public/change-password/change-password.jsp

**app-security-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          https://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd" >
    
    <security:http
        auto-config="false"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        use-expressions="true"
        request-matcher="ant"
        disable-url-rewriting="true"
    >
        <security:headers>
            <security:hsts disabled="true"/>
            <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </security:headers>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        
        <!-- Set up URL security for specific pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/home" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/contents" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/change-password" 
        
        <!-- Fall back for any other secure/* pages - user must be authenticated -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        
        <!-- Allow anonymous access for any URLS not secured above -->
        <security:anonymous username="ANON" granted-authority="AUTH_ANON" />

        <!-- Set up concurrent session control, the logout page, and the access denied handler -->
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/public/login?expired=true" />
        </security:session-management>
        
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout"
                         invalidate-session="true"
                         success-handler-ref="logOutSuccessHandler"
        />
        
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/public/forbidden" />
        
        <!-- Set up form login authentication, wiring up the success/and failure handlers -->
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/public/login" 
            login-processing-url="/public/security_check"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        />
            
    </security:http>
 
    
    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.app.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/secure/home" />
        <property name="localeResolver" ref="localeResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.app.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/public/login?failed=true" />
        <property name="changePasswordUrl" value="/public/change-password" />
        <property name="suspendedUrl" value="/public/suspended" />
        <property name="deletedUrl" value="/public/deleted" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="logOutSuccessHandler" class="com.app.application.util.spring.security.DefaultLogOutSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="logOutUrl" value="/public/logout" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean class="com.app.application.security.DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor"/>
    
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value="AUTH_" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <property name="expressionHandler">
                        <bean id="expressionEvaluator" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Set up the authentication manager, giving it our security service and setting up the password hashing.  We must manually create the encoder and salt source
    beans as they are required by our security service. 
    -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.app.application.security.domain.password.Sha1DigestGenerator" />
    <bean id="saltSource" class="com.app.application.security.domain.password.UsernameSaltSource" />
    
    <!-- Configure password generator and password validator -->
    <bean id="passwordGenerator" class="com.app.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordGenerator">
        <property name="randomStringGenerator">
            <bean class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.ApacheCommonsLangRandomStringGenerator" />
        </property>
        <property name="digestGenerator" ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
        <property name="passwordValidator" ref="passwordValidator"/>
        <property name="generatedPasswordLength" value="8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="passwordValidator" class="com.app.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordValidator" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  
    <!--  Spring context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/com/amor/**/*-config.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/**/*-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>htmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <!--  Application Exit Cleanup Listener --> 

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.app.web.mvc.context.ApplicationExitCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- OpenSessionInViewFilter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- Spring security -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>     
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    
    <!-- Spring servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>public</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/public-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>public</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>secure</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/secure-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>secure</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Other tomcat options -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/public/forbidden</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/public/error</location>
    </error-page>
    
</web-app>
```

**public-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.app.web.mvc.PublicController" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!--<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>-->
    
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/public/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

PublicChangePasswordController.java

```
@PublicController
@RequestMapping("/change-password")
@SessionAttributes("changePasswordFormObject")
public class PublicChangePasswordController {

    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    public PublicChangePasswordController(SecurityService securityService) {
        super();
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new ChangePasswordFormObjectValidator(securityService));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/change-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display(WebRequest webRequest) {

        String username = (String) webRequest.getAttribute(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.PASSWORD_CHANGE_USERNAME, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(username)) {
            // Redirect if no username is found on the session - user must have accessed it directly
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        }

        ChangePasswordFormObject formObject = new ChangePasswordFormObject();
        formObject.setUsername(username);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("change-password/change-password");
        modelAndView.addObject("changePasswordFormObject", formObject);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changePassword(@ModelAttribute("changePasswordFormObject") @Valid ChangePasswordFormObject formObject, BindingResult bindingResult,
            WebRequest webRequest, SessionStatus sessionStatus) throws Exception {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "change-password/change-password";
        }

        ChangePasswordDetailsDto changePasswordDetailsDto = new ChangePasswordDetailsDto();
        changePasswordDetailsDto.setUsername(formObject.getUsername());
        changePasswordDetailsDto.setNewPassword(formObject.getNewPassword());

        securityService.changePassword(changePasswordDetailsDto);

        webRequest.removeAttribute(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.PASSWORD_CHANGE_USERNAME, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

default public controller

```
@PublicController
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class DefaultPublicController {

    private String servletContext = "public/";

    @RequestMapping
    public String handle(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf(servletContext) + servletContext.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your classPublicChangePasswordController annotated with `@RequestMapping("/change-password")`.

Method display() has `@RequestMapping(value = "/change-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. So your link is already: */change-password/change-password* which is not right. remove annotation in display() method and just use @GetMapping

```
@GetMapping("/change-password")
public ModelAndView display(WebRequest webRequest) {
    // Method implementation
}
```

**Also you can update changePassword() with @PostMappting, but don't forget to add path: */save***

According to comment:
Check this code in your xml. There is two <mvc:annotation-driven />, but maybe should be mvc:annotation-driven and <mvc:annotation-driven />

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.app.web.mvc.PublicController" />
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and play with this line. because you are updating ModelAndView

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("public/change-password/change-password");
```

Comment: still getting the same error after doing this - edited the post to include my default public controller now too